# Set css values programmatically from MVC's model

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc

In my cshtml file, I have the following model directive

```
@model Model.Common.CameraPopupModel
```

How can I set Model.CustomHeight to the max-height property in css

```
<style>
    .customBootboxWidth {
        width: 1300px;
    }
     .restrictBodyHeight {
         max-height: 420px; /*set Model.Height here instead of hardcoding */
         overflow-y: auto;            
     }
</style>
```

What would be the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, assuming the `style` is in the view:

```
<style>
    .customBootboxWidth {
        width: 1300px;
    }
    .restrictBodyHeight {
        max-height: @(Model.CustomHeight)px;
        overflow-y: auto;            
    }
</style>
```